# Using a mathmatical model made in Matlab, in c# program

Tags: c#, matlab

I have a mathematical model of an ROV (remotely operated vehicle) in Matlab that I am trying to use in a c# program. The c# program will call the Rov model and passes some values to the model and then use the results from the model in the program.

The problem is that when the c# programs runs, an error massage is showing up saying: [image]

I tried to google the error massage and found some answers such that the directory is not right or the function 'mod' in the error massage is not in licence and other solutions but no one helped with this error.

The used Matlab version is 2022a and visual studio 2022.

The code in c# that calls the Matlab function is the following.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


namespace WayPointModel
{
    public class ROV
    {
        public static Data ROVmini(double[] x, double[] tau, double[] vCurrNed)
        {
            object[] x1 = x.Select(d=> (object)d).ToArray();
            object[] tau1 = tau.Select(d=> (object)d).ToArray();
            object[] vCurrNed1 = vCurrNed.Select(d => (object)d).ToArray();
            MLApp.MLApp matlab = new MLApp.MLApp();
            matlab.Execute(@"cd C:\Users\abdhab\Documents\MATLAB\DP\1DautodepthTest");
            object result = null;
            matlab.Feval("ARSmini", 2, out result, x1, tau1, vCurrNed1);
            double[] res = result as double[];
            double [] xDot = res[..12];
            double[] vCurrBody = res[11..];
            return new Data { xDot = xDot, vCurrBody=vCurrBody };
            
        }
    }
}
```

and the Matlab function is the following.

```
function [xdot, v_curr_body] = ARSmini(x, tau, v_curr_ned)

if (length(x) ~= 12),error('x-vector must have dimension 12!'); end
if (length(tau) ~= 6),error('tau-vector must have dimension 6!'); end

nu = x(1:6);
u = nu(1);
v = nu(2);
w = nu(3);
p = nu(4);
q = nu(5);
%nu(6) = 0.1;
r = nu(6);

eta = x(7:12);
phi = mod(eta(4),2*pi);
theta = mod(eta(5),2*pi);
psi = mod(eta(6),2*pi);



tau_u = tau(1);
tau_v = tau(2);
tau_w = tau(3);
tau_p = tau(4);
tau_q = tau(5);
%tau(6)=0.01;
tau_r = tau(6);


if (nargin == 2)
    v_curr_ned = [0 0 0]';
else
    R_n_b = Rzyx(phi, theta, psi)';
    v_curr_body = R_n_b*v_curr_ned;
end
    
nu_r = nu - [v_curr_body' 0 0 0]';

M_RB = [...
    90 0 0 0 0 0
    0 90 0 0 0 0
    0 0 90 0 0 0
    0 0 0 10 0 0
    0 0 0 0 15 0
    0 0 0 0 0 13];
M_A = [...
    54 0 0 0 0 0
    0 72 0 0 0 0 
    0 0 360 0 0 0
    0 0 0 11 0 0
    0 0 0 0 43.5 0
    0 0 0 0 0 5.2];
M = M_RB + M_A;

D_lin = [...
    250 0 0 0 0 0
    0 200 0 0 0 0
    0 0 175 0 0 0
    0 0 0 20 0 0
    0 0 0 0 20 0
    0 0 0 0 0 15];
D_n = [...
    350*abs(nu_r(1)) 0 0 0 0 0
    0 350*abs(nu_r(2)) 0 0 0 0
    0 0 400*abs(nu_r(3)) 0 0 0
    0 0 0 100*abs(nu_r(4)) 0 0
    0 0 0 0 100*abs(nu_r(5)) 0
    0 0 0 0 0 75*abs(nu_r(6))];
D = D_lin + D_n;


W = 90*9.81;
B = W/0.99;
r_bg = [0 0 0.18];
r_bb = [0 0 0];
 
g = gvect(W, B, theta, phi, r_bg, r_bb);

C = [...
    0 0 0 0 450*nu_r(3) -162*nu_r(2)
    0 0 0 -450*nu_r(3) 0 144*nu_r(1)
    0 0 0 162*nu_r(2) -144*nu_r(1) 0
    0 450*nu_r(3) -162*nu_r(2) 0 18.2*nu_r(6) -66.5*nu_r(5)
    -450*nu_r(3) 0 144*nu_r(1) -18.2*nu_r(6) 0 21*nu_r(4)
    162*nu_r(2) -144*nu_r(1) 0 66.5*nu_r(5) -21*nu_r(4) 0];

J = eulerang(eta(4),eta(5),eta(6));

area_rov =  [0.65*0.5; 0.9*0.5; 0.9*0.65];
cd = [1.05; 1.05; 1.75];
f_curr = 0.5 * 1000.*area_rov.*nu_r(1:3).*abs(nu_r(1:3)).*cd;

xdot = zeros(12,1);
xdot = [...
    M \ (tau - D * nu - g - C*nu_r - [f_curr;0 ; 0 ;0])
    J * nu];% + [v_curr_ned' 0 0 0]'];

end
```

Comment: mod is a elementary function in matlab, no toolboxes or anything. Its just the modulus. The issue is that the MATLAB codeis no correct. `eta(4)` seems to be a `cell array`, which the function does not accept. Write some input parsing in that matlab fucntion, e.g. some type asserts, to make sure you are actually inputing the types that you think you are.

Comment: First step in using a Matlab script with C# is making sure the Matlab script runs. [Here's a link to a similar question](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/349370-unable-to-use-mod-function-on-cell-array) at Matlab Central.

Comment: `phi = mod(eta(4),2*pi)` gives the error that the input to `mod` is a cell array. `eta` is a subset of `x`, and `x` is an input to your function. Thus, `x` is a cell array instead of a numeric array. It seems to me that the way you convert the C# double array to a MATLAB array is wrong. I don’t know anything about C#, so can’t help you fix it, but hopefully this gives you a hint.

Comment: I recommend starting with a simpler script, that just prints the properties and values of the input data. That way you can check that you do the interop correctly.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was a missing Matlab package. The missing package is MSS(Marine System Simulator) and after downloading the package everything went well. Thanks to all that commented on the question.